# Hard drive messed up after dual install of windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, permissions, file-corruption, check-disk

I installed windows 10 on Hard Drive B (HDB). Then plugged in Hard Drive A (HDA) so I could copy over some files.

It prompted me that I needed admin access to access the files so I clicked continue.

Then I restarted the PC and booted into HDA.

My taskbar pinned applications were saying that they missing.

The start menu search is showing 0 results found for common search such as "bluetooth", "device manager", or "programs and features".

uBlock origin in firefox is no longer working.

Dev tools (F12) in firefox is showing a blank white bar.

When I go to access a folder on my desktop, it says things like "you need admin to access this file".

When I go to open a text file, it says

```
You do not have permission to open this file. 
See the owner of the file or an administrator to obtain permission
```

The `C:\Users` folder has the attributes of "Read-only" half checked.

When I try to take ownership of that folder by setting "Everyone" to have "Full control".
It says:

```
An error occurred while applying security information to: 
C:\Users 
The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable
```

When I do chkdsk. It says:

```
Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 97B39
is corrupt.
  672256 file records processed.
File verification completed.
 Phase duration (File record verification): 6.31 seconds.
  6948 large file records processed.
 Phase duration (Orphan file record recovery): 0.00 milliseconds.

Errors found.  CHKDSK cannot continue in read-only mode.
```

When I do chkdsk /f. It says:
Cannot lock drive.

When I restart the PC, it says

```
press any key to skip disk checking
```

I don't press anything.

It says

```
Scanning and repairing C:\ drive
```

Then loops again saying to press any key and repairing C:\ drive, but no other message.

When I try to use 7-zip to archive everything, it has a bunch of files that says

```
Access is denied
```

So I can't use dskchk to repair the drive and can't take ownership of all the folders I used to own.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Why are you referring to HDA and HDB when they're typically used to denote legacy (PATA) hard disks? and windows never has used that notation? What do you mean "booted into HDA" - does HDA have another OS on it? Sounds like you borked one or more windowses. Have you tried the microsoft forums?

Comment: I'm referring to the hard drives as A, B instead of 1, 2 since it was suppose to make things easier to read. Its been so long since floppy disks that I didn't think anyone would take it literally.  Both drives had windows 10 installed on them. Basically, I installed win 10 on a second drive. When I connected the primary drive. Win10 corrupted it and messed with all the permissions instantly. Had to reinstall win10 on the primary drive and will never connect two drives at the same time again since windows hasn't been reliable since 7.

Comment: hda and hdb are common syntax in real OSes. So I wondered if you were trying to dualboot windows and one. Windows hasn't been reliable since '95, or BOB, whichever one is more hilarious for you. It's likely you borked some UEFI/secureboot thing. windows expects it is the only OS installed, and going by your story, wont even tolerate older versions of itself. What you want could potentially be achieved by hypervisoring, or sandboxing, or VMing.